# SQL Server Database stuck in Restoring... state

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to configure a mirror for a Test database between two SQL Server 2008 R1 SP1 Servers: A1 and A2

I'm doing a full backup of Test database on A1 and then trying to restore it on A2 with NORECOVERY option but database stucks in Restoring... mode. I've also tryed using WITH REPLACE option but no use

What might be wrong? The database is only one table with one row, i don't have any transactions it's just newly created database

Comment: @Derek but will i be able to set partner after in order for mirror to active? I'm following sql server standart mirroring guide

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448088/sql-2008-mirroring-in-restoring-state

Comment: So you are saying it must be in restoring state when it's a secondary database that is not currently used and the primary database is active?

Comment: Yes, that is correct